# Can a kafka consumer group freeze during a rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Can a rolling deployment of a Kafka consumer group cause the group to freeze?

So let's consider this scenario,

1. we start a rolling deployment
2. one consumer leaves the group
3. Kafka notices this and triggers a rebalance (hence consumption stops)
4. rebalance happens but soon a new consumer wants to join
5. also another consumer leaves
6. again a new rebalance happens
7. (loop till deployment is complete)

So if you have a large enough cluster and it takes some time for the deployment to get completed on one machine (which is usually the case), Will this lead to a complete freeze in consumption?

If yes, What are the strategies to do a consumer group update in production

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's definitely possible. There have been a number of recent improvements to mitigate the downtime during events like this. I'd recommend enabling one or both or the following features:

[Static membership](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-345%3A+Introduce+static+membership+protocol+to+reduce+consumer+rebalances) was added in 2.3 and can prevent a rebalance from occurring when a known member of the group is bounced. This requires both the client and the broker to be on version 2.3+

[Incremental cooperative rebalancing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-429%3A+Kafka+Consumer+Incremental+Rebalance+Protocol) enables the group to have faster rebalances AND allows individual members to continue consuming throughout the rebalance. You'll still see rebalances during a rolling deployment but they won't result in a complete freeze in consumption for the duration. This is completely client side so it will work with any brokers, but your clients should be on version 2.5.1+

Comment: For `Static membership` -> I can understand that, (along with the client/broker should be on 2.3+) adding `group.instance.id` at client side should be enough.

But for the `Incremental cooperative rebalancing`, just the client version 2.5.1+ should be enough? I mean, is there any config specifically need to be done?

Comment: Yes, for a plain consumer group you need to set the partition assignor to the CooperativeStickyAssignor. The name of the actual config is "partition.assignment.strategy" (note, if you want to do a rolling upgrade, you'll have to follow a specific upgrade path to switch assignors. Basically you need two rolling bounces, the first one to add the CooperativeStickyAssignor to the partition.assignment.strategy list, and the second bounce to remove the old assignor. But if you're starting up a new app, you can just start out with the CooperativeStickyAssignor).

Comment: For a Streams application, cooperative rebalancing is enabled by default, so you don't have to do anything to turn it on.